# No results in Music lens after deleting rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, music, lenses, clementine

I removed Rhythmbox and installed Clementine. Now, the Music lens is empty. How can I search for music without Rhythmbox?

Comment: New Ubuntu User - you appear to have multiple accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to have your accounts merged.  Once done you will be able to edit your question with further details.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box - the only current media-player scopes available are banshee & rhythmbox.

Basically you cannot use clementine together with the music lens to search for music in Ubuntu 12.04 - however if you are an 12.10/13.04 or 13.10 user you are in luck.

For 12.10 & 13.04 users, the [scope-packagers](https://launchpad.net/~scopes-packagers) maintain a PPA which have the following media-player scopes in their package `unity-scope-music-extras`:

```
unity-scope-audacious Audacious Scope for Music Lens
unity-scope-clementine Clementine Scope for Music Lens
unity-scope-gmusicbrowser GMusicBrowser Scope for Music Lens
unity-scope-guayadeque Guayadeque Scope for Music Lens
unity-scope-musique Musique Scope for Music Lens
```

To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-scopes-music-extras
```

For 13.10 users, this has been split into individual packages and are available in the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-clementine
```